# View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN does not work properly

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I'm quite new in Android development. In my application, I use a class that is a part of all my activities. It allows me to define that all my application will be in full screen mode.

Here is the code of this class :

```
package com.retroverse.bataille_corse;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }
}
```

The full screen mode works perfectly, except in a very specific case. When I'm in my application, I press the "home" button of the navigation bar, then when I want to resume the application (only like this) by clicking on the "app menu" button of the navigation bar (when you see the applications that are still open) and resume the application, the notification bar reappears when it shouldn't (and only it, there's never any problem with the navigation bar)... But it disappears when I change activity.

Here is a video to better understand : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FPoADemhLcPfxnohQdfYOpb6wkxQTx5q

I also tried adding

```
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
```

But it didn't change anything (besides I don't really know what these 2 views are for)...

I really need help, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the status bar by going to each activity and set this in your OnCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
}
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for your more than informative answer, and it works wonders. The goal of my "FullScreenActivity" class was to cover all the functions needed to make the application work in full screen. So I tried to add your code, not to each activity, but to the "FullScreenActivity" class (still in the onCreate() method and keep my old code in onResume() ). And it works perfectly! Thanks again!
But I still have a question: why doesn't my code version work for the notification bar (and only in one case), while yours does?

Comment: I suspect it is because you are using setSystemUiVisibility() and I'm using setFlags(), or because I'm using inside OnCreate method and you are using inside OnResume. PS: If my answer works please don't forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I went to the Android developers documentation to see if there was an equivalent of `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` and others in `WindowManager` but apparently not... However, I did notice that it was better to "Use WindowInsetsController#hide(int) with Type#statusBars() instead" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_FULLSCREEN). I have read these articles but don't know how to use these new resources. Could you again help me?